# Percentage in maskedTextBox display improperly

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net-3.5, string-formatting, maskedtextbox

I'm trying to display a percentages in a MaskedTextBox the string being passed in its "40.99" but when it displays on the form it is "409.9%".

populating value

```
 if (_person.Percentage != null)
    maskedTextBoxPercentage.Text = _person.Percentage.ToString();
 else
 {
    maskedTextBoxPercentage.Text = 0.00.ToString();
 }
```

maskedTextBoxPercentage properties

```
 this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(437, 125);
 this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.Mask = "000.00%";
 this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.Name = "maskedTextBoxPercentage";
 this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(129, 20);
 this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.TabIndex = 65;
```

[image]

Comment: what do you want to show exactly?

Comment: @aliboy38 Right now i got it displaying correctly using "00.00%" as the mask , but it won't allow me to enter "100%"

Comment: just tell me if it gives you an error

Comment: @aliboy38 no error just ignore any input once it has four digits

Answer (score 1):

If you expect it to display "40.99%", change your mask to "00.00%"

Comment: I tried that somewhat. Tried using "000.00%", since it can be 100% but now it displays "409.9_%"

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
try
            {
                this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.Mask = "00.00%";

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.Mask = "000%";
            }
```

Or you can try this too :

```
try
        {
            this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.Mask = "00.00%";

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.maskedTextBoxPercentage.Text = "100%";
        }
```

Comment: This would be used at OnTextChanged    ?

Comment: I've never seen a try/catch used in InitializeComponent()

Comment: i didn't know you used in InitializeComponent(). try TextChanged

Comment: It doesn't seem to have an effect. Responds just as it did before.